# rename or replace the files in a folder

Tags: python, file, file-rename

I have a folder contains images. each image named as

```
abc_001.jpg 
abc_002.jpg
```

I need to rename the images by deleting the first text abc_ and start from the number

I did as

```
import os

path = '/Desktop/my_folder'

folder = os.fsencode(path)

filenames = []

for file in os.listdir(folder):
    filename = os.fsdecode(file)
    if filename.endswith ('.jpg'):
          filenames=filename.replace('abc_','')
```

but it doesn't work . how can I replace the first text or deleting them?

i tried

```
for file in os.listdir(folder):
    filename = os.fsdecode(file)
    if filename.endswith ('.jpg'):
        filenames = filename.replace('abc_', '')
        os.rename(filename, filenames)
```

but got

```
 os.rename(filename, filenames)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'abc_000000000009.jpg' -> '000000000009.jpg'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem so anyone who faces the same problem can try it

```
for file in os.listdir(folder):
    filename = os.fsdecode(file)
    if filename.endswith ('.jpg'): 
        filenames = filename.replace('abc_', '')
        os.rename(os.path.join(path,filename), os.path.join(path,filenames))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os.rename(source, destination)` to rename either file or directory

where source is your file path, and destination is the new file name path

Comment: i got FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'abc_' ->

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `os.rename(src, dst)` instead of `filename.replace`. Let me know if you have any issues.

You need to rename the file in the following order:

```
for file in os.listdir(folder):
    filename = os.fsdecode(file)
    if filename.endswith ('.jpg'):
          new_file_name=filename.replace('abc_','')
           os.rename(filename, new_file_name)
```

Comment: i got FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'abc_' -> ''

Comment: see my updated solution.. you need to replace `abc_`  with your normal string replace method and pass the new file name to `os.rename`

Comment: thanks, i will try it but what I the f here and file_names ? `os.rename(f, file_name)`

Comment: did you mean ` filenames = filename.replace('abc_', '')
        os.rename(filename, filenames)`

Comment: Yes, I have updated the snippet with your code.

Comment: thanks for your effort but the folder has several images and got this `os.rename(filename, filenames)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'abc_000000000009.jpg' -> '000000000009.jpg'` but I checked again and the image exists